# Loop over start date and end date through strtotime not working PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, strtotime

I've an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 2010-09-16
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [end_date] => 2010-10-16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 2011-12-24
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [end_date] => 2012-01-23
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 2012-11-10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [end_date] => 2012-12-10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 2013-05-14
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [end_date] => 2013-06-13
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 2014-10-20
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [end_date] => 2014-11-19
        )

);
```

I've written following `foreach` loop to iterate over an array and in foreach loop I want to get date between start date and end date by using `while loop` through `strtotime` (Referencing [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-loop-through-dates-from-date-to-date-with-strtotime-function/) article)

```
foreach ($dateArray as $key => $data) {
            $start_date = $dateArray[$key]['start_date'];
            $end_date = $dateArray[$key]['end_date'];

            while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
                echo "$start_date\n";
                $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
            }
}
```

But its taking lot of time to loading the page and showing wrong output something like:

```
1970-01-02
1970-01-03
1970-01-04
1970-01-05
1970-01-06
1970-01-07
.
.
.
```

and so on...

But if I'm passing hard code value to it like:

```
foreach ($dateArray as $key => $data) {
            $start_date = $dateArray[$key]['start_date'];
            $end_date = $dateArray[$key]['end_date'];

            while (strtotime('2009-12-06') <= strtotime('2020-12-31')) {
                echo "$start_date\n";
                $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
            }
        }
```

Then its working fine and showing proper result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: because when you define start time and end time which time its consider as and time in while loop at very first time ? this issue arising every time

Comment: @jilesh: sorry I didn't get you..please elaborate

Comment: Your starting array you posted is wrong. what is a var_dump of `$dataArray[$key]`?

Comment: `dateArray[$key]` is correct and showing proper

Comment: Why -ve.. plz explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array_chunk($dateArray,2);
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
        $start_date = data[0]['start_date'];
        $end_date =data[1]['end_date'];

        while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
            echo "$start_date\n";
            $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. All the given answer are working for me but which one will be good for performance wise because data is huge.

Comment: it is better to  restructure  your array  in 
     $date[0] => ['start_date' => '2016-01-01', 'end_date' => '1016-01-10' ]
     $date[1] => ['start_date' => '2016-01-01', 'end_date' => '1016-01-10' ]
     ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
foreach ($dateArray as $key => $data) {

    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        if ($end_date != '') {
            $end_date = '';
        }
    }


    if (isset($dateArray[$key]['start_date'])) {
        $start_date = $dateArray[$key]['start_date'];
    }

    if (isset($dateArray[$key]['end_date'])) {
        $end_date = $dateArray[$key]['end_date'];
    }


    if ($start_date != '' && $end_date != '') {
        while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
            echo "$start_date\n";
            $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. All the given answer are working for me but which one will be good for performance wise because data is huge.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to access a value you do not have access to. What you are trying to do for each iteration is :

[0]['StartDate']

[0]['EndDate']

and doing this for each iteration of the loop, from your array structure it should be :

[0]['StartDate']

[1]['EndDate']

if you always know that the end date is on the next iteration of it you can do something like this :

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($dateArray); $x = $x + 2) 
{
     if(isset($dateArray[$x + 1]))
     {
        $start_date = $dateArray[$x]['start_date'];
        $end_date = $dateArray[$x + 1]['end_date'];

        //preform calculation
        while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
            echo "$start_date\n";
            $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day",                 strtotime($start_date)));
        }

     }
}
```

but you should store the array in a different way if you want to use your current code :

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 2010-09-16
        [end_date] => 2010-10-16
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. All the given answer are working for me but which one will be good for performance wise because data is huge.

Comment: The other two are O(n), but mine are O(n/2) i think. So i think mine should be the best one i you are thinking about number of loops. But i'm not sure.

Comment: Btw, it would be the same as formating the array as this :
[0] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 2010-09-16
        [end_date] => 2010-10-16
    )